# Visual studio command line not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012

I have a .exe that uses a .png as argument. If I use cmd and do "x.exe y.png" it will work just fine(the image is in the project's folder). But in VS, I went to project properties->debugging->command arguments and included the y.png there, yet it doesn't work(I think it doesn't detect it as being an argument).

Did I include it wrong, or do I have to do something else?

Comment: Visual studio executes the program from other path than you execute it from cmd

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check the main class declaration. That's how I solved my problem.

Answer (score -1):

Nevermind, I made it work. I had to include it for both release and debug. Not sure exactly why.

Comment: I think you should at least try to post your snippets.